# Daydream Controller App Button in WebVR

Tags: three.js, google-vr, webvr, daydream

According to; 
https://developers.google.com/vr/discover/daydream

The Daydream controller features:

- A touch pad that allows users to interact with virtual objects or easily scroll through a media collection.
- ***An app button that you have complete control over for your experience.***
- A home button ....................
- Volume controls ..................

.

In the three.js DaydreamController.js

**// app button not available, reserved for use by the browser**

Can anyone explain the discrepancy.

I would like another button to re-centre the gamepad only.

(to comply with "UX-D6: App recenters appropriately with respect to the experience ; https://developers.google.com/vr/distribute/daydream/design-requirements)